# placeholder color not changeing in pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

how i can change placeholder color in pyqt5 i try Different solutions on google but it didn't work

I made an example so you might understand better

**example**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 110, 311, 41))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit,QTextEdit {border: 2px inset rgb(37, 39, 49);border-radius: 10px;color: rgba(255, 255, 255,1);padding-left: 5px;padding-right: 5px;padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 5px;background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.0600746, y1:0.926, x2:0.96, y2:0.0340909, stop:0.233831 rgb(43, 45, 56), stop:0.865672 rgba(40,40,40,0.3));}QLineEdit:hover,QTextEdit:hover {border: 2px solid rgb(49, 50, 62);}QLineEdit:focus,QTextEdit:focus {border: 2px inset rgb(85, 170, 255);background-color: rgb(43, 45, 56)}")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Dialog", "how change this color to white rgb(255,255,255)"))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**how change this color to white**

Comment: TYPO: [`placeholderText()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#placeholderText) is the function returning the QBrush relative to that palette role. [`setColor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#setColor) accepts a [`ColorRole`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#ColorRole-enum) enum, that uses a different and *capitalized* syntax, just like any other constant: `PlaceholderText`. Remember that casing is important, and it's consistent even ignoring the naming style: no matter if you're using CamelCase/mixedCase or snake_case, classes and constants should *always* have a capitalized name.

Comment: i changed to this `paleta.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.ColorRole.PlaceholderText, QtGui.QColor("white"))` it dosnt have Error But the text PlaceholderText is still black

Comment: As explained in the documentation about [`setPalette`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#palette-prop), you shall *"not use this function in conjunction with Qt Style Sheets"*. Also, as said in the [property selector](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) documentation: *"If the value of the Qt property changes after the style sheet has been set, it might be necessary to force a style sheet recomputation."*. I think I can provide an answer, but I ask you to provide a valid [mre] (as you should always do) to work with so that the answer will be more reliable and complete.

Comment: all i need changing PlaceholderText to white And this is fixed

Comment: And, since I can only partially reproduce the issue, I need a MRE to work with.

Comment: I added the files related to the program design to the question. The program has not been completed yet and I have not sent any files that are not related to the program design. You may receive an error at runtime @musicamante

Comment: No, questions must be self contained, code must be included in the question. Also, I **specifically** asked for a *minimal, reproducible example*. Sorry but this is not a help desk, nor a debugging service. If you want help, you must do your part in providing what's being requested.

Comment: when i set backgroun to dark and color to white placeholdertext stiil black and user cant see it how change that to white Where these questions need further explanation Tell me exactly so I can explain to you

Comment: @musicamante I change Question The way you said

Comment: If you see the placeholder text still in black, then it's probably related to [QTBUG-92199](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-92199), which affects Qt>5.15.2. Please post your current Qt version (`print(QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR)`), OS and the output of `print(app.style().objectName())`.

Comment: im useing same version in the code Exampel i send when i run the program placeholder its same with color and when i change color text place holder also changed  but i do not konw why in real app other dialog box i use still have black placeholder with same stayle

Comment: im useing same version in the code Exampel i send when i run the program placeholder its same with color and when i change color text place holder also changed  but i do not konw why in real app other dialog box i use still have black placeholder with same stayle

Comment: So, are you saying that with the code above, the placeholder color is *correct*, but in your program not? If that's the case, then it means that your code does **not reproduce** the issue, so it's not a valid MRE. We cannot help you if you don't provide the correct code that allows us to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By QLineEdit's setStyleSheet() you get it.

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 110, 311, 41))
        style = '''
            QLineEdit, QTextEdit {
                border: 2px inset rgb(37, 39, 49);
                border-radius: 10px;color: rgba(255, 255, 255,1);
                padding-left: 5px;
                padding-right: 5px;
                padding-top: 5px;
                padding-left: 5px;
                background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.0600746, y1:0.926, x2:0.96, y2:0.0340909, stop:0.233831 rgb(43, 45, 56), stop:0.865672 rgba(40,40,40,0.3));
            }
            QLineEdit:hover,
            QTextEdit:hover {
                border: 2px solid rgb(49, 50, 62);
            }
            QLineEdit:focus,
            QTextEdit:focus {
                border: 2px inset rgb(85, 170, 255);
                background-color: rgb(43, 45, 56)
            }

            /*  --- HERE --- */
            QLineEdit[text=\"\"]{
                color: green;
            }

        '''
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet(style)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Dialog", "how change this color to white rgb(255,255,255)"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Hope this helps